# What are the calls allowed by QuickBooks Web Connector?

Tags: web, quickbooks

My client has two Companies on the same QBES (Enterprise), in other words, two Company files.
We are creating a Web Application (Angular + Web Api 2) to automatically generate Purchase Orders based on new Sales Receipts created by their ecommerce integration plug-in (probably SkuVault), we need then to create the Sales Order in Company B based on this PO, and after that, the Bills and Invoices respectively. I found all the calls I should be calling on the SDK documents, but since this architecture requires us to use Web Connector, will I be able to make all the calls listed on the SDK using the Web Connector?

Answer (score 2):

> What are the calls allowed by QuickBooks Web Connector?

All of them.

> will I be able to make all the calls listed on the SDK using the Web Connector?

Yes.

**More details:**

The Web Connector is just a SOAP wrapper around the normal QuickBooks SDK calls. It's nothing special or magical or even very technical in nature, it's just a simple SOAP wrapper around the rest of the XML-based COM SDK. So, anything you can feed to QuickBooks normally, you can feed via the Web Connector.